# Invalid argument supplied Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

My program is not working properly, i do not know what should i do :S

I got this error message:
[image]

Take a look at this:
[image]

Here is my code:
My controller file (Home):

```
    <?php

    class Home extends CI_Controller{

         public function __construct(){
             parent::__construct();

             $this->load->model("Crudmodel");

        }


 public function index(){

    # get all data in Study table
    $selectStudys = $this->Crudmodel->selectStudys();


    foreach ($selectStudys as $key => $study) 
    {
        # get UserNames
        $user = $this->Crudmodel->getName($study['user_id']);

        #get Subject Names
        $subject = $this->Crudmodel->getSubName($study['subject_id']);


        #append both NEW VALUES to same array

        if(!empty($user[0]['username'])){
        $data[$key]['user_id'] = $user[0]['username'];
        // your main problem can be this. may be it is not getting value from query this is why we have put validation on model function and error handler condition here
        }else{
         $data[$key]['user_id'] = ''; // or anything as your else condition you can use as error handler 
        }
        if(!empty($subject[0]['name'])){
        $data[$key]['subject_id'] = $subject[0]['name'];
        // your main problem can be this. may be it is not getting value from query this is why we have put validation on model function and error handler condition here
        }else{
           $data[$key]["subject_id"] = "";
          // or anything you can use as error handler
        }

    }


    $data['records'] = $selectStudys;
    $this->load->view('home', $data);

}

}
?>
```

Crudmodel:

```
       class Crudmodel extends CI_Model{

        public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();

         $this->load->database();

        }


        function selectStudys()
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cursadas");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
       $result = $query->result_array();
     }else{
      $result = "";
          // or anything you can use as error handler
      return $result;
    }
}

function getName($name)
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM usuarios WHERE id = $name ");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
    $result = $query->result_array();
    }else{
    $result = "";
          // or anything you can use as error handler
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Dont know what to do now :(

Hope you can help me :S

Comment: please check if "$selectStudys " is an array or not ?

Comment: @Purushottamzende you mean 
print_r($selectStudys)?

Comment: It seems that your query returns 0 rows, and it uses default case of `$result=""` which it returns to you. Do var_dump($selectStudys) before your foreach.

Comment: @Dimi what should i do then pal?

Comment: @Programming_guy Well, first of all post the result of the var_dump($selectStudys); We want to make sure that it is indeed the issue. And replace your else with `$result=array();` instead of `$result=""` in your selectStudys function

Comment: @Dimi i already di it pal, i got this errors:
https://i.gyazo.com/d357112135b16f111d03e2ed6b066f21.png
https://i.gyazo.com/420c667662bf6220dc8059de2fe98d92.png
The code:
https://i.gyazo.com/0f4d58faf5f21f92b624bceb9ec75c0f.png

Comment: @Programming_guy oh I found it...... move your `}` right after `$result=""` or `$result=array()`..... You were not returning any results if you found any because your return was in your else statement which gets triggered only when there are no results...

Comment: @Dimi you mean this pal?
https://i.gyazo.com/56e06b961b5f32b01c4d5df5df42f905.png

Comment: yes. Does this work now? or does it still create errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140092/discussion-between-dimi-and-programming-guy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the model. You only return something inside the `else`. Easy fix, move the `return`.

You should probably return an empty array if there are no rows. Then the `foreach` will still have something to work with - even if it is empty. `foreach` will choke if given something that cannot be used in a loop - a string for instance.

```
function selectStudys()
{
    $query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cursadas");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
       $result = $query->result_array();
     }else{
      $result = array();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Mate igot this error now:
https://i.gyazo.com/e4d927cd2801208c06c587c12d630de9.png
Code error line:
https://i.gyazo.com/baf4ceb5f6f9959cecbb670f01e9dc62.png

Comment: Maybe because you changed `$selectStudys = $this->Crudmodel->selectStudys();` to `$a= $this->Crudmodel->selectStudys();`

Comment: EDIT: the program shows the table but it does not fetch anything :(
https://i.gyazo.com/6fbe430aa613c5504db78cc9f59a9395.png

Comment: Mate, can you take a look at this :S :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264008/error-fetching-data-codeigniter

Comment: Hey, I was working on an answer for the question you linked (and deleted). Got it figured out?